# how to make my ios App bigger(disk size)

Tags: ios

For some reason my boss think the bigger an IOS app is, the better it will be. I finish the app he wants but he thinks it's not good enough because it's on 13M. So what should I do, put a music in project?

Comment: you should tell him he's crazy that's what you could do

Comment: LMFAO, maybe put some random pictures in the project, but not displaying it.

Comment: but, you can use bigger images, with better resolutions. This will add disk size AND you're using it, so your project is not poluted by unused code/image/things

Comment: Oh waw, some people are really stupid. Your boss has probably something that need to compensate for ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a big file that would not be used in app, an image, or just a data file with random data in it.

Or you could explain to your client that a smaller app is easier to download for the end user.